# Google Drive: Why I am getting Page Token when no files are there to fetch ? What is the solution?

Tags: google-app-engine, google-drive-api

I am listing files by using following query:

```
String query=new String("'"+Id+"' in parents and  mimeType != 'application/vnd.google-apps.folder' and trashed = false" );
```

By setting next page token, when I execute the same query I see null Files List returned.

More Detail Explanation of Issue:
If there are no files to fetch it should return null page token right? Instead it returning page token and when I am looping the query I get null FilesList.

I tried the same in Try It of following link which has same output as in my program
https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/files/list
I have 7 folders and 3 files in the folder that I have specified in my request with maxLimit 5. I am trying to fetch only files.

Why I am getting Page Token when no files are there to fetch? What is the solution?

Answer (score 0):

What you see is the unfortunate way in which this api works.
The api filters out files not in your query *after* it gets the page, so if all items in the page were filtered out it will be empty.
You have to keep querying the next pages until the last page to make sure you got all the files. Yes its very inneficient and confusing. Dont try using a large page size to 'fix' this as you will then get other errors like timeouts.

Comment: What is the max page size that may result in timeout? If I use page size of 50 what is the probability of getting time out? What if I make many calls(max 50) to API in a loop will I see timeout?

Comment: there is no fixed number. page size of 50 is small, but making several calls in a row will get you eventually a quota error. Look at exponential backoff.